# Setting backgroundImage style from a FileReader

Tags: javascript, styles, filereader

I am looking for a solution that allows me to take a file from a file upload input and preview it by setting the document.body.style.backgroundImage.

The following code works to display a preview in an Image element:

```
function setImage(id, target){
  input = document.getElementById(id);
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      target.src = e.target.result;
    };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Where id is the id of the `<input type='file'>`, and target is the `<img>` element.

The following code outlines what I would like to happen, however e.target.result is of `data:image/png;base64` format and clearly does not work where css requests a url.

```
  function setBackgroundImage(id){
    input = document.getElementById(id);
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
          document.body.style.backgroundImage = e.target.result;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use `url()` around the URL:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + e.target.result + ')';
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I thought it should have worked! I can't accept this answer for another 11 minutes.