# Giving src of img tag dynamically from asp:fileupload control

Tags: html, asp.net, image, file-upload, jcrop

This looks quite challenging and may be impossible to do it the way i want.I have an html Image (img tag) and i want to use an image which i upload from the asp:FileUpload control.I am facing a lot of problems but this is the only way out for me at the moment.I have tried the below :

```
     <img id="target" alt="[Example]" runat="server" />
```

with code-behind :

```
     target.Src = "~/Images/" + fileName;
```

Dont worry about filename,it works just fine.The image gets uploaded and works just fine.BUT cropping is disabled since the image is still on the server.So, how can i use an image on client side? any other suggestions?

Can we just give the src of img dynamically by using Eval?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Image control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image(v=vs.110).aspx/)
 and set the image in server side.

Or for cliente side, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename)!

Comment: I dont want to use the server.I want to use the image on client side and so i am using an html image control