# css hide "Choose File" button but display file after select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file

I would like to make custom button for an image upload. I am able to get this result with the demo below:

https://jsfiddle.net/algometrix/fgrbyo4z/

But HOW CAN I DISPLAY the file name selected after? Or maybe even a thumbnail of an image if possible? Like after I choose a file from the window that pops open I would like it to display 'the file name' on the page after I selected it.

Javascript - jQuery is totally an option here if anyone can help in that area.

HTML

```
<div>
  <div style="display:block;text-align:center;margin-top:20%;">
    <label for="files"> <span class="btn">Select Image</span></label>
    <input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" id="files" class="form-control" type="file" name="files">

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3f88b8;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Javascript.  Is that an option?

Comment: Try following links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the addition of javascript, we can just watch for the `change` event on the input, and put the name on the page.  Please note these minor HTML changes:

```
<div class="file-upload">
  <label for="upload-1" class="btn">Upload</label>
  <input type="file" id="upload-1">
  <p class="file-name">Please select a file.</p>
</div>
```

With this jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
         var filename = $(this).val();
         $(this).closest('.file-upload').find('.file-name').html(filename);
    }
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/78ff413a/)

Answer (score 3):

Just tap into the change event of the file element:

```
 var file = document.getElementById("files");
 file.addEventListener("change", function(){ alert(this.value); });
```

Shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbg44bqu/12/

Answer (score 1):

This script shows the image as soon as uploaded:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img').show().attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#files").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgrbyo4z/12/)

Comment: Thanks WcPc, I have one quick question. How can I send this image through a form I have set up? Like can I have javascript add this file to my form data and then when I submit the form can I then send this image as data with my current form?

Comment: You do not need js for this, just add the form tags around it: `<form action="my.php" method="post">` and then in your PHP (I assume you use PHP): `var your_file = $_POST['control_name']` for example `var your_file = $_POST['files']` Even though you show the image already it is still selected in your fileupload control...