# CSS: How to hide file input but keep the filename?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the file input "Choose file" button but I want to keep the filename. How can I do this?

[image]

```
<input
  name="upload"
  id="upload-input"
  placeholder="Select a file"
  ref="fileInput"
  type="file"
  required>
```

Comment: This isn't tagged javascript - is that acceptable? If so, this has been asked / answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819391/css-hide-choose-file-button-but-display-file-after-select

Answer (score 3):

You can save the file name to another html element and then hide the choose file input like this.

```js
function getFileName()
{
var x = document.getElementById('upload-input')
x.style.visibility = 'collapse'
document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = x.value.split('\\').pop()
}
```

```html
<input
  name="upload"
  id="upload-input"
  placeholder="Select a file"
  ref="fileInput"
  type="file"
  required 
  onchange="getFileName()"><span id="fileName"></span>
```

Comment: You can use x.value.split('\\').pop() for filename instead of path

Comment: OP doesn't have the question tagged with javascript.... your solution requires javascript... might be worth clarifying if javascript is OK, and / or if it's possible / not possible with pure HTML / CSS.

Comment: Additionally, if JS is the answer, then this should be closed as duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819391/css-hide-choose-file-button-but-display-file-after-select) instead of posting a new answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following css:

```
::-webkit-file-upload-button,
::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
::-webkit-file-upload-button,
::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Can you add an example snippet to prove it.

Comment: I just added a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

following worked for me:

```css
input[type="file"] {
    width: 280px;
    line-height: normal;
    height: 32px;
    /* display: none; */
}
input::-webkit-file-upload-button,
input::file-selector-button {
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  content:"";
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border:none;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="file"">
```

it basically hides the button, filename is still clickable though

Answer (score 0):

Add a new component at the place:

```
 <span id='upload-file-name'></span>
```

With JavaScript, to get the file name first

```
var em = document.getElementById("upload-input");
var fname = em.name;
```

Hide the file upload input field

```
em.style.display = 'none';
```

Put the file name to this new component

```
document.getElementById("upload-file-name").innerHTML = fname;
```

Comment: OP doesn't have the question tagged with javascript.... your solution requires javascript... might be worth clarifying if javascript is OK, and / or if it's possible / not possible with pure HTML / CSS.

Comment: Additionally, if JS is the answer, then this should be closed as duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819391/css-hide-choose-file-button-but-display-file-after-select) instead of posting a new answer

Comment: @cale_b The OP did not put limitation on any possibility.

Comment: Absolutely OP did: the tags indicate the technologies that are desired.  that's what tags are for.  You wouldn't post a PHP answer to a question tagged Ruby....

Answer (score 0):

you could use the color attribute in transparent in css to hide the letters of the filename but the button does not know

```css
.inputfile{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input
  name="upload"
  id="upload-input"
  placeholder="Select a file"
  ref="fileInput"
  type="file"
  class="inputfile"
  required>
```

If you want to hide it you must put: display: none;
But everything will be hidden without being able to use it. But if you want it to be invisible by regulating the opacity and adjusting the input it can work for you. But if you want to hide the button and the letters you can not put color: "any color"

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div which will display the name of your file after choose it. And then, hide your input file with display none.

So use jquery or Javascript onchange or onclick event to do it