# Client side only: upload image in bootstrap modal and pull image for display inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have an odd project I'm working on.  Using only HTML, CSS, and Javascript/Jquery, I have a form running inside a bootstrap Modal with a file upload.

The upload needs to be saved to a certain folder on the Hard Drive, and then pulled in for display inside a div.

I need help in assigning the image to a variable and having the src work regardless of filename.

There can be no server side techniques used, as this is for a raspberry pi that will not be connected to the internet.

Comment: You can't upload anything without client side. You need to have a server to upload.

Comment: Can you use [HTML5](https://helloacm.com/how-to-read-local-files-using-html5-filereader/)?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename