# How to display images in templates using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Using Django. In a template i want an image that if the user wants to change the photo, he just needs to click in the image already presented and then the file explorer is opened so that a new image can be chosen. Then the new image must be preview in the template in place of the old one temporarily.

the program is opening the file explorer, i choose the new image but the old image isn't change and the new image isn't displayed in any place of the html too
my code:

```
<script>

// Quando a imagem da pessoa for clicada
document.getElementById("imagem-pessoa").addEventListener('click', function() {
// Abrir o explorador de arquivos ao clicar no campo de arquivo oculto
document.getElementById("input-imagem").click();
});

// Quando uma nova imagem for selecionada
document.getElementById("input-imagem").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
// Capturar a nova imagem selecionada
const novaImagem = event.target.files[0];
// Atualizar temporariamente a imagem no HTML
const urlNovaImagem = URL.createObjectURL(novaImagem);
document.getElementById("imagem-pessoa").src = urlNovaImagem;
});
</script>
```

and the html

```
<img class="rectangle" id="imagem-pessoa" src="{{ pessoa.imagem.url }}" alt="Imagem da Pessoa">>
<input type="file" id="input-imagem" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
```

it aren't working

what i expected is: "a person registration page is loaded, receiving a number that searches the database and returns a person from the database. It then fills in some elements on the screen with the data found in the database table about that person. Among the people model objects there is a model.ImageField that stores a photo of each person." What I need is: I want the image found referring to the person that was searched for (in the people table) to be presented in the html, but at the same time I want it so that if the user wants to change the photo, he just needs to click on it of the image already presented and then the file explorer is opened so that a new image can be chosen. Once the new image has been chosen, the new image must be displayed in the html in place of the old one temporarily, but the replacement of the photo in the database must only be carried out after a submit button is clicked

Comment: You should create a reader here and have an onload event listener on that reader. You should only process the file once it has loaded. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369027/13349935

Comment: Actually, your code [seems to work as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/dcuyLrhp/). Have you checked the event is fired, or is there any error messages in the console?

Comment: It looks like you don't know what is "console". Please hit F12 to open an entirely new aspect to front end debugging.

Comment: @Teemu, i checked there isn't any error on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

To make this functionality work in a template HTML in Django, see this code:

```js
'use strict'

let photo = document.getElementById('imgPhoto');
let file = document.getElementById('flImage');

photo.addEventListener('click', () => {
  file.click();
});

file.addEventListener('change', () => {  
  if (file.files.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  let reader = new FileReader();  
  reader.onload = () => {
    photo.src = reader.result;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<div class="marg">
  <div class="maxSize">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img style="object-fit:cover;" src="{{ pessoa.imagem.url }}" alt="Imagem da Pessoa" id="imgPhoto">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="file" id="flImage" name="flImage" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this code in index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="rectangle" id="imagem-pessoa" src="{{ pessoa.imagem.url }}" alt="Imagem da Pessoa">
<input type="file" id="input-imagem" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">

<script>

    // Quando a imagem da pessoa for clicada
    document.getElementById("imagem-pessoa").addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Abrir o explorador de arquivos ao clicar no campo de arquivo oculto
    document.getElementById("input-imagem").click();
    });
    
    // Quando uma nova imagem for selecionada
    document.getElementById("input-imagem").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // Capturar a nova imagem selecionada
    const novaImagem = event.target.files[0];
    // Atualizar temporariamente a imagem no HTML
    const urlNovaImagem = URL.createObjectURL(novaImagem);
    document.getElementById("imagem-pessoa").src = urlNovaImagem;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Do you use Live-Server on VSCode?

Comment: @elmur i dont know this extension, but do i need this even if i'm using Django?

Comment: No, It is used to show real time changes on html files

Comment: And do you have any idea about how i solve my problem?